# is their is any size limit of the protocol buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server, protocol-buffers

I am passing the data from my client to server and vice versa . I want to know is their is any size limit of the protocol buffer .

Comment: What do you mean by size limit? Message size limit, or serialization limit ?

Comment: @MarkoBencik I am talking about the message size limit .

Comment: No there is no limit unless you plan to go into GB region then I think it is 4 Gb

Answer (score 2):

Citing the [official source](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#large-data):

> Protocol Buffers are not designed to handle large messages. As a general rule of thumb, if you are dealing in messages larger than a megabyte each, it may be time to consider an alternate strategy.
>
> That said, Protocol Buffers are great for handling individual messages within a large data set. Usually, large data sets are really just a collection of small pieces, where each small piece may be a structured piece of data. Even though Protocol Buffers cannot handle the entire set at once, using Protocol Buffers to encode each piece greatly simplifies your problem: now all you need is to handle a set of byte strings rather than a set of structures.
>
> Protocol Buffers do not include any built-in support for large data sets because different situations call for different solutions. Sometimes a simple list of records will do while other times you may want something more like a database. Each solution should be developed as a separate library, so that only those who need it need to pay the costs.

---

As far as I understand the [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) the following applies:

- varints above 64-bit are not specified, but given how [their encoding works](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) varint bit-length is not limited by the wire-format (varint consisting of several `1xxxxxxx` groups and terminated by a single `0xxxxxxx` is perfectly valid -- I suppose there is no actual implementation supporting varints larger than 64-bit thought)
- given the above varint encoding property, it should be possible to encode any message length (as varints are used internally to encode length of length-delimited fields and other field types are varints or have a fixed length)
- you can construct arbitrarily long valid protobuf messages just by repeating a single repeated field ad-absurdum -- parser should be perfectly happy as long as it has enough memory to store the values (there are even parsers which provide callbacks for field values thus relaxing memory consumption, e.g. [nanopb](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/docs/concepts.rst#field-callbacks))

(Please do validate my thoughts)